# Linux Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, keyword

Can you give me a sample on how to filter a certain keyword like for example "error" in the /var/log/messages and then send email if it finds real-time word for error.

I would just like to watch for error keyword in the /var/log/messages and then send it to my email address.

Answer (score 1):

simply grepit.

```
tail -f log.log | grep error
```

This will list you all error you can then mail them

Comment: If you want to continue scanning, the above won't allow since it'll remain TAILing until you CTRL-C. It will show on-screen, yes, but then nothing else will happen.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is this: 
On a regular basis (which you decide), you:

- copy the main file to another file
- you DIFF on that file, only taking out the newly added parts (if the file is sequentially written, this will be a nice and clean block of lines, at the end of the file)
- you copy the main file to the other file, again (this sets the new reference for the next check)
- then you GREP on whatever you want, in the block of lines you've found 2 steps back
- you report the found lines, using the wanted method (mail,..)